# Using @font-face with webpack and vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js, sass

Having some trouble understanding webpack, and getting some simple stuff working.

I have my font files in:

```
/src/assets/fonts/
brands.eot
brands.svg
brands.ttf
brands.woff
```

And I'm referencing them in my SASS from:

```
/src/assets/sass/0-plugins/_brands.sass

@font-face
  font-family: "brands"
  src: url("../fonts/brands.eot")
  src: url("../fonts/brands.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/brands.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/brands.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/brands.svg#brands") format("svg")
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal

.brand-stack-overflow:before
  content: "\47"
```

Which gets eventually imported to:

```
/src/assets/sass/main.sass
```

When I try and use this in the normal way, however, the icon is not displaying. Referenced like so in my .vue component file:

```
<i class="brand-stack-overflow"></i>
```

Webpack isn't giving me any errors, and I'm using Webpack version 3.6

Also, I'm using the webpack boilerplate, and have not been given a webpack.config.js file.

Comment: What does the generated CSS look like? What does the console say? It should give you 404s for those font files

Comment: It appears I was just testing it with icons I never included in the actual font files, unless something else I tried fixed something too. Assumed it was Webpack, as it was the first time I used it.